# TIdTCPServer OnExecute fires multiple times

Tags: delphi, indy

I have an app that receives a TCP socket connection from another app, processes the content that is streamed across the socket, builds a request based on the received data, sends the request using TIdHTTP to an external server, processes the response, and sends an ack back to the tcp client.

```
procedure TMyClass.TCPExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  s: AnsiString;
begin
  s := TransferTCPBytesToString(AContext.Connection.IOHandler);
  // test string for terminating characters
  if Pos(#28#13, s) > 0 then
  begin
  //********PROBLEM: THIS WILL BE CALLED MULTIPLE TIMES 
  //********WITH THE SAME COMPLETE DATA STREAM CONTENT!
    BuildAndSendExternalRequest(s);
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
    // send the response back to tcp client
    WriteTCPResponse(AContext.Connection.IOHandler);
  end;
end;

function TMyClass.TransferTCPBytesToString(AnIOHandler: TIdIOHandler): AnsiString;
begin
  if AnIOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
    Exit;
  // read message from tcp client connection
  AnIOHandler.ReadBytes(FTCPBytes, AnIOHandler.InputBuffer.Size, True);
  SetLength(Result, Length(FTCPBytes));
  // copy message bytes to string
  Move(FTCPBytes[0], Result[1], Length(FTCPBytes));
end;

procedure TMyClass.WriteTCPResponse(AnIOHandler: TIdIOHandler);
var
  bytes: TBytes;
begin
  // FTCPBytes contains data from tcp client
  // bytes will contain processed response from external server
  BuildACK(FTCPBytes,bytes);
  // FTCPBytes now contains ACK data
  AnIOHandler.WriteDirect(FTCPBytes, Length(FTCPBytes));
end;
```

The request/response cycle completes successfully; the response sent back to the tcp client requestor is correct and the process executes and completes as expected.

However, because the OnExecute event fires multiple times with the same data, two requests are received, built, sent, acknowledged etc.

In looking at the logs on the tcp client app, the logs only show one request being sent. Not sure what is going on here. But I need to make sure that the request/response cycle is 1-1, not 1-many!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the OnExecute event fires multiple times ...

It is supposed to, as it is a *looped* event. The loop runs for as long as the connection is alive. The code inside your `OnExecute` event handler is responsible for deciding what happens on each loop iteration.

The *ideal* situation is where the event handler receives 1 message from the client, sends 1 response back to the client, and then exits, so that the next loop iteration is ready to handle the next request/response pair.

Which, based on your description, you are trying to do, but the code shown is not handling that very well. Most notably, the code is not accounting for the byte-stream nature of TCP. It does not differentiate one incoming message from another.  It just dumps the entire `IOHandler.InputBuffer` content as-is into an `AnsiString` (why an `AnsiString`?), and if that `AnsiString` happens to contain the delimiter `#28#13` then you are processing the entire `AnsiString` and then throwing it away, losing anything received after the delimiter (ie, part of the next message).  And if the `AnsiString` doesn't contain the delimiter, then you are still throwing away the `AnsiString`, thus losing all data received so far for the current message before the delimiter arrives.

If all of your messages are delimited by `#28#13`, then I suggest you use the `IOHandler.ReadLn()` or `IOHandler.WaitFor()` method to read each message properly.

Also, you are re-using the same `FTCPBytes` member for both input and output, which in of itself is wrong, but you are also not providing any concurrent access protection for it if you have multiple client connections present.

With that said, try something more like this instead:

```pascal
procedure TMyClass.TCPConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_8Bit;
end;

procedure TMyClass.TCPExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  s: String;
  response: TIdBytes:
begin
  s := TransferTCPBytesToString(AContext.Connection.IOHandler);
  BuildAndSendExternalRequest(s, response);
  // send the response back to tcp client
  WriteTCPResponse(AContext.Connection.IOHandler, response);
end;

function TMyClass.TransferTCPBytesToString(AnIOHandler: TIdIOHandler): String;
begin
  // read message from tcp client connection
  Result := AnIOHandler.ReadLn(#28#13);
  or:
  Result := AnIOHandler.WaitFor(#28#13);
end;

procedure TMyClass.BuildAndSendExternalRequest(const Msg: String; var Response: TIdBytes);
begin
  // send Msg to external server as needed...
  // store response bytes in Response...
end;

procedure TMyClass.WriteTCPResponse(AnIOHandler: TIdIOHandler; const Response: TIdBytes);
var
  bytes: TIdBytes;
begin
  // Response contains processed response from external server
  BuildACK(bytes, Response);
  // bytes now contains ACK data
  AnIOHandler.Write(bytes);
end;
```

> ... with the same data

That is not possible given the code you have shown.  The call to `IOHandler.ReadBytes()` in `TransferTCPBytesToString()` is reading and discarding all bytes from the `IOHandler.InputBuffer`, so there is no way the same bytes can still be in that buffer when `TransferTCPBytesToString()` is called again at a later time. So, the only way you could be seeing the same data over and over is if the client is sending the same data over and over to begin with.

Comment: Excellent explanation/clarification (as usual!).  Thank you!

Comment: A couple of things, since I didn't provide much info. The streamed data is about 64k, so trying to do a readln() will result in a max line length exceeded error; calling waitfor never finishes.  There will only be 1 client connecting at a time, synchronously, so no need to block the FTCPBytes variable. The only client connects, sends, waits for the ACK, disconnects. So any remaining data in the FTCPBytes var should be able to be cleared in the OnDisconnect event, correct?

Comment: @DeCoder "*The streamed data is about 64k, so trying to do a readln() will result in a max line length exceeded error*" - the *default* line length is 16K, but you can change that using the `IOHandler.MaxLineLength` property, or the optional `AMaxLineLength` parameter of `ReadLn()` itself. `IOHandler.WaitFor()` has no length limit. "*calling waitfor never finishes*" - the only way that can happen is if the specified delimiter is never received. Which would affect `IOHandler.ReadLn()`, too. Is EVERY message terminated with the same delimiter?

Comment: @DeCoder "*The only client connects, sends, waits for the ACK, disconnects. So any remaining data in the FTCPBytes var should be able to be cleared in the OnDisconnect event, correct?*"- I suppose so, but I would suggest simply eliminating `FTCPBytes` altogether. You don't really need it, as my example demonstrates.

Comment: All messages are suffixed with #28#13. This gives us the ability to identify complete messages between applications. On a separate note, this URL: http://ww2.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/index.EN.aspx no longer works. Where can I download the latest documentation for Indy?

Comment: @DeCoder: https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/337

Comment: @DeCoder "*All messages are suffixed with #28#13*" - then ReadLn/WaitFor should work just fine. "*Where can I download the latest documentation for Indy?*" - see https://www.indyproject.org/2021/02/10/links-to-old-indy-website-pages-are-currently-broken/

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I ultimately implemented with ReadLn(). Note: Using the second parameter on ReadLn() didn't work. I was still getting max line length exceeded errors. So I implemented this way:

Comment: AnIOHandler.MaxLineLength := K128k; // 128 * 1024
  if AnIOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
    Exit;
  Result := AnIOHandler.ReadLn(#28#13);

Comment: Thanks for the documentation references!

Comment: @DeCoder The 2nd parameter of `ReadLn()` is `ATimeout`, did you mean the 3rd parameter, `AMaxLineLength`? I know for a fact that parameter works just fine. In any case, if you use the `MaxLineLength` property, you don't need to set it on every read, just set it once, such as in the `OnConnect` event